# Trouble specifying type parameter when inheriting from generic class

Tags: python, generics, python-typing, pyright

I have some code similar to this minimal example:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Protocol, NamedTuple

class SupportsFoo(Protocol):
    foo: int

T = TypeVar("T", bound=SupportsFoo)

class A(Generic[T]):
    def method(self, arg: T) -> T:
        return arg

class FooBar(NamedTuple):
    foo: int
    bar: int

class B(A[FooBar]):
    def method(self, arg):
        print(arg.bar)
        return arg
```

Pyright reports the following error message, even though I have specified `T`, which is bound to `SupportsFoo`, to be `FooBar`.

```
Cannot access member "bar" for type "SupportsFoo*"
  Member "bar" is unknown
```

Studying the Python documentation, I find (see [User-defined generic types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types)):

> When inheriting from generic classes, some type parameters could be
> fixed:
>
> ```py
> from collections.abc import Mapping from typing import TypeVar
>
> T = TypeVar('T')
>
> class MyDict(Mapping[str, T]):
>     ...
> ```
>
> In this case MyDict has a single parameter, T.

Given this, I would expect my code to type check without problems. Why is Pyright complaining? Any help in fixing (or understanding) this problem is highly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** The signature of `method` inferred by Pyright is

```py
(method) def method(
    self: Self@B,
    arg: T@A
) -> T@A
```

Why is `T@A` still occurring here? Shouldn't Pyright infer `FooBar` instead?

Comment: You cannot just _omit_ the type annotation of `arg`. You are **overriding** `method` in the subclass. A type checker cannot just assume that the type is the `FooBar`. You could override it and make it more restrictive for example (that would be type safe). You could theoretically make it a whole different type (that would _not_ be type safe, but still possible). I am not sure, why `T@A` is what Pyright chooses to show here, but it does not really matter. You need to specify the type of `arg`.